# not able to select the row where the last inserted id is [Mysql, php pdo oop]

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

i'm facing this Problem when i try to select the last inserted id from Mysql table, i get the value = bool(true) instead of the values.

What i'm trying to do:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                if (isset($_POST['paName']) && isset($_POST['paEmail']) && isset($_POST['paTel']) && isset($_POST['aName']) && isset($_POST['Artnum'])){
                    
                    if (!empty($_POST['paName']) && !empty($_POST['paEmail']) && !empty($_POST['paTel']) && !empty($_POST['aName']) && !empty($_POST['Artnum'])){
                        
                         $paName = $_POST['paName'];
                         $paEmail = $_POST['paEmail'];
                         $paTel = $_POST['paTel'];
                         $aName = $_POST['aName'];
                         $Artnum = $_POST['Artnum'];
                      
                        $query = "INSERT INTO crud (paName,paEmail,paTel,aName,Artnum) VALUES ('$paName','$paEmail','$paTel','$aName','$Artnum')";
                       if ($sql = $this->conn->exec($query)){
                           $id = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
                           $query = "SELECT * FROM crud WHERE id = '".$id."'";
                           $stmt=$this->conn->prepare($query);
                           $stmt->execute();
                           var_dump($stmt->execute());die();
}
```

but if i do the same without conditions, i get all values from the table , so that's mean my condition is wrong.

can you tell me please what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are missing `$this->conn->prepare()` in first query. You can try this example :

`lastInsertId()` only work after the INSERT query.

**Correct:**

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO crud (paName,paEmail,paTel,aName,Artnum) 
                              VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);");
$sonuc = $stmt->execute([$paName,$paEmail,$paTel,$aName,$Artnum]);
$LAST_ID = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
```

**Incorrect:**

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO crud (paName,paEmail,paTel,aName,Artnum) VALUES ('$paName','$paEmail','$paTel','$aName','$Artnum')";
$sonuc = $this->conn->execute($stmt);
$LAST_ID = $this->conn->lastInsertId(); //always return string(1)=0
```

Comment: Although it is not "missed" but intentionally written this way, but of course a prepared statement is how it should be done